# Unhandled Runtime Error Error: Failed to fetch+ SWR+NEXT JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have migrated my app from react `17.02` to use the latest version. recently from [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/react-18/overview).

I am trying to use `/api` routes to fetch data at client side using `SWR`.

`lib/fetch`

```
export default async function fetcher(...args) {
  const res = await fetch(...args);
  if (!res.ok) throw new Error('Failed to fetch');
  return res.json();
}
```

This is inside in `/pages/dashboard`:

```
  const { data, error } = useSWR(process.env.APP_URL + '/api/user', fetcher, { suspense: true });

  const router = useRouter();

  useEffect(() => {
    setUser(data);
    console.log(series);
  }, [data, user]);
  if (error) {
    router.push('/404');
  }
 return (
    <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
      <div className="h-screen max-w-7xl mx-auto px-4 bg-background-dark">
        <Header title="Dashboard" />
        <h1 className="text-5xl text-white">You will see all the series here</h1>
      </div>
    </Suspense>
  );
```

`env.local`

```
APP_URL=http://localhost:3000
```

The application tries to go to this `url`.

```
http://localhost:3000/undefined/api/user
```

[image: runtime_error]

Comment: Environment variables need to be prefixed with [`NEXT_PUBLIC_`](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables#exposing-environment-variables-to-the-browser) to be exposed to the browser. In this case you don't even need an environment variable though. Just make the request to `/api/user` instead, i.e. `useSWR('/api/user', fetcher, { suspense: true })`.

Comment: I was using `localhost` becuase `/api/user` throws `Server Error
TypeError: Only absolute URLs are supported`.